# Android development: Visual Studio + Java. Is it possible (worth a try)?

Tags: java, android, visual-studio

I know there are (expensive) framework which let you write android apps in VS C# and compile it to android apk.

I also know, that it is possible to write Java application in VS ([link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93)).

Is it possible, maybe even not harder than in Eclipse, writing android apps in Visual Studio using some free plugins/frameworks/tools?
Is it possible to compile androids apps, and debug it in phone/virtual device?

In the near future I think using Android Studio would be best choice.

Comment: Even though I think the answer is a resounding "NO!!!"  I'm voting this up, because it's something I considered once, and is probably something others will wonder, so it'll be helpful to others.

Comment: It would probably be useful if you do Mono for Android...

Comment: I would use `Mono for Android` but it is simply too expensive for me. I want to learn writing android apps, I don't know where would it lead me to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply write them in Java using Eclipse. VS is not optimized for Java and Eclise has a larger ecosystem of useful plug-ins. Using VS for Android development is like designing a web-site with assembler: It is simply not made for that :).

You are asking whether it is worth a try. Well "a try" compared to what? Are you currently developing apps using other IDEs or have you never developed android apps and you only know VS and want to try it there?

If you already use other IDEs keep those. If this is your first android project, using Eclipse is easier, as written above.

Comment: I really don't like eclipse, it's slow, it doesn't look OK for me and its hard for me to write using eclipse

Comment: I'm a .NET developer who LOVES Visual Studio, and only rarely has to do Java work, and I concur 100%.  Even though I occasionally feel lost in Eclipse due to the fact that I almost never use it, I wouldn't dream of trying to use VS for Java just because I'm used to VS.  There's a lot to be said for using the right tool for the job.  Eclipse is a very good tool, and it really doesn't take too long to get used to.

Comment: I think it is less hard to use eclipse than trying to abuse Visual Studio and try to get it working with Java. Compiling and debuggin alone will be an issue.

Comment: @PoweRoy: Agree. And Eclipse is not slow on a modern machine. In addition, it is one of the most widely used tools for Java, so by learning it you increase your value as a programmer since many companies use it. Of course, you can also use other Java IDEs like stated in the other answer. Just. not. VS.

Comment: As far as Android integration, tools, code completion, and debugging are concerned, eclipse is king.  The latest version, Juno, is much faster than the older versions and I've even noticed better performance with Juno than with VS 2010.  If it's a matter of environment, you can change the colors in eclipse to match VS and even change the key bindings.  I was a VS exclusive guy myself and I've grown rather accustomed to using eclipse and prefer it in most cases now.

Comment: @gexicide "a try": I mean, if it is possible to write android apps in VS, is worth to do it there.

Comment: Sure, if the only problem with Eclipse was that it is a different way of doing things. I have used Eclipse 8hrs every week day since the new year. I miss Visual Studio's robustness and form designer. XML is clunky and like learning HTML again (horror). JPadPro was robust when I was at university. What happened to that? My main issue with Eclipse is its 'cross platform' nature. I use the Win7 version. Does Eclipse run better on another OS? It is as if Eclipse has been forced to compile on Win7, instead of being the target. What should I run it on?

Answer (score 6):

I find myself in the same situation as you: Visual Studio is my main IDE, but I'm currently working on an Android project.

I suggest that you give Eclipse another try. The Android SDK integrates very nicely into Eclipse: for example, you have a graphical UI editor, which feels similar to the WPF editor in Visual Studio. Yes, Eclipse takes getting used to, and switching between both will be a hassle, due to subtle differences in the keyboard shortcuts (Jump to Definition is F3 in Eclipse and F12 in VS; IntelliSense Autocomplete is Enter in Eclipse and Tab in VS, etc.), but you will be rewarded by using "the right tool for the task".

Answer (score 6):

It is now possible to build and debug Java in Visual Studio. Enjoy.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/11/06/java-debugging-and-language-support-in-visual-studio-for-android/

Comment: OP asked if it's possible, so I provided a source confirming that it is. Also, my experience with Android Studio was pretty bad, so I would give Visual Studio a chance.

Comment: Well, it's probably possible to drive a nail using your fist only. But it may be painful experience

Comment: I guess that's why OP asked the question to begin with, to avoid the painful experience Android Studio is able to provide.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would use Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA to do my Android development, as they are both native Java IDE's.

You also might want to check out [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en).  It is an integrated IDE into the Android platform.  You can write code on your Android device, and the IDE can deploy and launch the app from the IDE.  It makes testing on a device easy, and it even integrates with other services, such as DropBox and GitHub.

On the other hand, to develop on it you would have to be a glutton for punishment.  Try writing an entire app on a tablet/phone.  It isn't easy...

Comment: Its just ` native Java IDE's` or `pure  native Java IDE's` ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered Android Studio?

From there you can update your key-bindings (aka: shortcuts):

**Preserve Visual Studio key mappings:**

```
o   File | Settings | Key Bindings 
      KeyMaps | Visual Studio copy
o   Reset a key-shortcut
        Select a command in the Settings window and enter a key-combination
```

**Some commands to consider:**

```
      Build solution
       •    Other | Build
               Ctrl + Shift + B

   Renaming variables, methods, files, etc.
       •    Main Menu | Refactor | Rename…
               Ctrl + R, R

   Code Generation
       •    Main Menu | Code | Generate
               Ctrl + Period
```

Comment: Yes I tried Android_Studio, And I won't try again till that I have low end pc. VS is double more better in performance.